# Why did my edit become two edits?

Tags: support, edits, grace-period

I edited a question and saved it, and within less than two minutes, I edited and saved it again. I thought that edits within five minutes are conflated as one edit. However, the edits became separate edits. How come this happened? It is [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29316252/revisions). Is this a bug?